# Object, Component and Control Specification

Tags: enyo

May anyone explain what exactly is an Object, a Component and a Control. Also, how does each of them differs from each other? What i know is that a control is a component which interacts directly with DOM node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Enyo entities are `Object`s; it's the root of the Enyo object Tree.  `Component` is the base for most of the 'interesting' kinds within Enyo and derives from `Object`.  `Component` introduces the idea of the nested hierarchy in Enyo, published properties and events.  See more here:  https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Creating-Components.  `Control`s are `Component`s that have a DOM node associated with them, as you said.  You can see more here:  https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Creating-Controls.

As you move up the tree within Enyo child objects inherit from their parents.  So, `Control` has all the methods, properties, etc. that `Component` has, as well as the ones `Component` inherited from `Object`.

You might also want to check out my book: [*Enyo: Up and Running*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027751.do)